# How to parse nested Json in SQL Server

Tags: json, sql-server, api

I retrieved JSON from an API (part of json file was showed at the bottom). I was hoping to parse the json and store in SQL table. With the following SQL query, there was only 1 row returned. How can I return all rows with table headers NAME JobNum Water Sewer ? I tried while loop using variable to replace `[0]` after `$.items`, but seemed not to work. I wasn't sure if the structure of json file works for cross apply.

```
DECLARE @MondayComApi VARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @MondayComApi = BULKCOLUMN
FROM OPENROWSET(BULK'D:/temp/a.json', SINGLE_BLOB) JSON

IF (ISJSON(@MondayComApi) = 1)
BEGIN
    PRINT 'JSON File is valid';

    SELECT NAME, JobNum, Water, Sewer 
    FROM OPENJSON(@MondayComApi, '$.data.boards')
    WITH (
        NAME VARCHAR(100) '$.items[0].name',
        JobNum VARCHAR(100) '$.items[0].column_values[0].text',
        Water VARCHAR(100) '$.items[0].column_values[1].text',
        Sewer VARCHAR(100) '$.items[0].column_values[2].text'
    )
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    PRINT 'JSON File is invalid';
END
```

The following was part of the JSON - I reduced content of "items" to shorten length:

```
{
  "data": {
    "boards": [
        {
            "items": [
                {
                    "name": "Holmes Project",
                    "column_values": [
                        {
                            "title": "Job",
                            "text": "D1210"
                        },
                        {
                            "title": "Water",
                            "text": "YES"
                        },
                        {
                            "title": "Sewer",
                            "text": "YES"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "Lake Short Project)",
                    "column_values": [
                        {
                            "title": "Job",
                            "text": "D1014"
                        },
                        {
                            "title": "Water",
                            "text": "YES"
                        },
                        {
                            "title": "Sewer",
                            "text": "YES"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "Chase Project",
                    "column_values": [
                        {
                            "title": "Job",
                            "text": "D2101"
                        },
                        {
                            "title": "Water",
                            "text": "NO"
                        },
                        {
                            "title": "Sewer",
                            "text": "YES"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "Juanita Project",
                    "column_values": [
                        {
                            "title": "Job",
                            "text": "D1102"
                        },
                        {
                            "title": "Water",
                            "text": "YES"
                        },
                        {
                            "title": "Sewer",
                            "text": "YES"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "Lowry Project",
                    "column_values": [
                        {
                            "title": "Job",
                            "text": "D1014"
                        },
                        {
                            "title": "Water",
                            "text": "YES"
                        },
                        {
                            "title": "Sewer",
                            "text": "YES"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
},
"account_id": 5687438790
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I moved more of the JSON path out of `WITH` and into `OPENJSON`:

```
SELECT NAME, JobNum, Water, Sewer 
FROM
    OPENJSON(@MondayComApi, '$.data.boards[0].items')
        WITH (
            NAME VARCHAR(100) '$.name',
            JobNum VARCHAR(100) '$.column_values[0].text',
            Water VARCHAR(100) '$.column_values[1].text',
            Sewer VARCHAR(100) '$.column_values[2].text'
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, `SINGLE_BLOB` should be `SINGLE_CLOB` if it is ANSI or UTF-8 data.

Next, to break out a JSON array into separate rows, you need `OPENJSON` *without* a schema, then you use `OPENJSON` again on each row, where `key` column contains the index, and `value` contains the object.

> If `boards` always contains only one object in its array, you can remove the second `OPENJSON` and change the path of the first to `$.data.boards[0].items`

Then we can break out the `column_values` and pivot them back up into a single row.

```sql
SELECT
    NAME = JSON_VALUE(item.value, '$.name'),
    cv.JobNum,
    cv.Water,
    cv.Sewer 
FROM OPENJSON(@j, '$.data.boards') boards
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(boards.value, '$.items') item
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT
        MIN(CASE WHEN title = 'Job' THEN [text] END) JobNum,
        MIN(CASE WHEN title = 'Water'  THEN [text] END) Water,
        MIN(CASE WHEN title = 'Sewer'  THEN [text] END) Sewer
    FROM OPENJSON(item.value, '$.column_values')
    WITH (
        title varchar(100),
        [text] varchar(100)
    ) column_values
) cv
```