Assistance with TSQL OPENJSON extracting metadata and data into table
I have this JSON:
{
    "environments": [
        {
            "environment": "Development",
            "customs": {
                "FieldA": "FieldA_Dev",
                "FieldB": "FieldB_Dev",
                "FieldC": "FieldC_Dev"
            }
        },
        {
            "environment": "Test",
            "customs": {
                "FieldA": "FieldA_Test",
                "FieldB": "FieldB_Test",
                "FieldC": "FieldC_Test"
            }
        },
        {
            "environment": "Production",
            "customs": {
                "FieldA": "FieldA_Prod",
                "FieldB": "FieldB_Prod",
                "FieldC": "FieldC_Prod"
            }
        }
    ],
    "customMetadata": [
        {
            "name": "FieldA",
            "default": "FieldA_Default",
            "description": "FieldA_Description"
        },
        {
            "name": "FieldB",
            "default": "FieldB_Default",
            "description": "FieldB_Description"
        },
        {
            "name": "FieldC",
            "default": "FieldC_Default",
            "description": "FieldC_Description"
        }
    ]
}

I am trying to build a SQL table like this:
CREATE TABLE #TempTable 
(
    [Name] NVARCHAR(255),
    [Default] NVARCHAR(255),
    [Description] NVARCHAR(255),
    [Development] NVARCHAR(255),
    [Test] NVARCHAR(255),
    [Production] NVARCHAR(255)
);

And then map the values from the JSON file.
I can do the initial metadata insert with:
INSERT INTO #TempTable ([Name], [Default], [Description], [Development], [Test], [Production])
SELECT 
    [name] AS [Name],
    [default] AS [Default],
    [description] AS [Description],
    NULL AS [Development],
    NULL AS [Test],
    NULL AS [Production]
FROM 
    OPENJSON(@json, '$.customMetadata') 
    WITH (
        [name] NVARCHAR(255) '$.name',
        [default] NVARCHAR(255) '$.default',
        [description] NVARCHAR(255) '$.description'
    );

But afterwards to map each of the environments' values into the table, I get stuck.
Please help.
I have tried with OPENJSON and CROSS APPLY JSON, and AI tool assistance, but just cannot get it right.

Try OUTER APPLY OPENJSON(@json,'$.enviroments')

this is similar example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68419013/how-to-parse-nested-json-in-sql-server

Why do you have two items in the "customMetadata" part of the parsed JSON with "name" equal to "FieldB"?

@Zhorov - thank you. I have edited and corrected the original post.

i made as 2 separate select statements . just to explain how to bound data:
working example here
Also, this post should give you more on subject:
SQL
declare @json nvarchar (max) = '{
    "environments": [
        {
            "environment": "Development",
            "customs": {
                "FieldA": "FieldA_Dev",
                "FieldB": "FieldB_Dev",
                "FieldC": "FieldC_Dev"
            }
        },
        {
            "environment": "Test",
            "customs": {
                "FieldA": "FieldA_Test",
                "FieldB": "FieldB_Test",
                "FieldC": "FieldC_Test"
            }
        },
        {
            "environment": "Production",
            "customs": {
                "FieldA": "FieldA_Prod",
                "FieldB": "FieldB_Prod",
                "FieldC": "FieldC_Prod"
            }
        }
    ],
    "customMetadata": [
        {
            "name": "FieldA",
            "default": "FieldA_Default",
            "description": "FieldA_Description"
        },
        {
            "name": "FieldB",
            "default": "FieldB_Default",
            "description": "FieldB_Description"
        },
        {
            "name": "FieldB",
            "default": "FieldB_Default",
            "description": "FieldB_Description"
        }
    ]
}'
  
  
SELECT 
    rn = ROW_NUMBER() over (order by (select 1)),
    [name] AS [Name],
    [default] AS [Default],
    [description] AS [Description],
    NULL AS [Development],
    NULL AS [Test],
    NULL AS [Production]
FROM 
    OPENJSON(@json, '$.customMetadata') 
    WITH (
        [name] NVARCHAR(255) '$.name',
        [default] NVARCHAR(255) '$.default',
        [description] NVARCHAR(255) '$.description'
    )


SELECT 
    rn = ROW_NUMBER() over (order by (select 1)),
    *
FROM 
    OPENJSON(@json, '$.environments') 
    WITH (
        environment NVARCHAR(255) '$.environment',
        FieldA NVARCHAR(255) '$.customs.FieldA',
        FieldB NVARCHAR(255) '$.customs.FieldB',
        FieldC NVARCHAR(255) '$.customs.FieldC'
    )


first table (yours):



rn
Name
Default
Description
Development
Test
Production




1
FieldA
FieldA_Default
FieldA_Description
NULL
NULL
NULL


2
FieldB
FieldB_Default
FieldB_Description
NULL
NULL
NULL


3
FieldB
FieldB_Default
FieldB_Description
NULL
NULL
NULL



second table -(what you are looking for)



rn
environment
FieldA
FieldB
FieldC




1
Development
FieldA_Dev
FieldB_Dev
FieldC_Dev


2
Test
FieldA_Test
FieldB_Test
FieldC_Test


3
Production
FieldA_Prod
FieldB_Prod
FieldC_Prod



so simple inner join will do trick:

 SELECT 
    FIRST_TABLE.*,
    SECOND_TABLE.*
 FROM
 (SELECT 
    rn = ROW_NUMBER() over (order by (select 1)),
    [name] AS [Name],
    [default] AS [Default],
    [description] AS [Description]
FROM 
    OPENJSON(@json, '$.customMetadata') 
    WITH (
        [name] NVARCHAR(255) '$.name',
        [default] NVARCHAR(255) '$.default',
        [description] NVARCHAR(255) '$.description'
    )
) FIRST_TABLE
INNER JOIN (
SELECT 
    rn = ROW_NUMBER() over (order by (select 1)),
    environment,
    FieldA,FieldB,FieldC
FROM 
    OPENJSON(@json, '$.environments') 
    WITH (
        environment NVARCHAR(255) '$.environment',
        FieldA NVARCHAR(255) '$.customs.FieldA',
        FieldB NVARCHAR(255) '$.customs.FieldB',
        FieldC NVARCHAR(255) '$.customs.FieldC'
    )
) SECOND_TABLE on FIRST_TABLE.rn = SECOND_TABLE.rn




rn
Name
Default
Description
rn
environment
FieldA
FieldB
FieldC




1
FieldA
FieldA_Default
FieldA_Description
1
Development
FieldA_Dev
FieldB_Dev
FieldC_Dev


2
FieldB
FieldB_Default
FieldB_Description
2
Test
FieldA_Test
FieldB_Test
FieldC_Test


3
FieldB
FieldB_Default
FieldB_Description
3
Production
FieldA_Prod
FieldB_Prod
FieldC_Prod




joining on rn might not map correctly... This depends on gapless well sorted data...

You did not explicitly state your expected output.
Furthermore, your JSON repeats FieldB. I'd assume a copy-paste error...
This is my suggestion:
SELECT Cust.[name]
      ,Cust.[default]
      ,Cust.[description]
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN Env.environment='Development' THEN JSON_VALUE(Env.customs, CONCAT('$.',Cust.[name])) END) AS ValueForDev
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN Env.environment='Test'        THEN JSON_VALUE(Env.customs, CONCAT('$.',Cust.[name])) END) AS ValueForTest
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN Env.environment='Production'  THEN JSON_VALUE(Env.customs, CONCAT('$.',Cust.[name])) END) AS ValueForProd
FROM OPENJSON(@json) WITH (environments NVARCHAR(MAX) AS JSON, customMetadata NVARCHAR(MAX) AS JSON) A

CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(A.environments) 
WITH (environment NVARCHAR(250)
     ,customs NVARCHAR(MAX) AS JSON) Env

CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(A.customMetadata)
WITH ([name] NVARCHAR(250)
     ,[default] NVARCHAR(250)
     ,[description] NVARCHAR(250)) Cust

GROUP BY Cust.[name],Cust.[default],Cust.[description];

The result
+--------+----------------+--------------------+-------------+--------------+--------------+
| name   | default        | description        | ValueForDev | ValueForTest | ValueForProd |
+--------+----------------+--------------------+-------------+--------------+--------------+
| FieldA | FieldA_Default | FieldA_Description | FieldA_Dev  | FieldA_Test  | FieldA_Prod  |
| FieldB | FieldB_Default | FieldB_Description | FieldB_Dev  | FieldB_Test  | FieldB_Prod  |
| FieldC | FieldC_Default | FieldC_Description | FieldC_Dev  | FieldC_Test  | FieldC_Prod  |
+--------+----------------+--------------------+-------------+--------------+--------------+

The idea in short:

The FROM uses OPENJSON to retrieve your main sections AS JSON.
Then we use CROSS APPLY OPENJSON() to dive into these sections using WITH() to get the content.
GROUP BY will reduce the output to one line per field.
The MAX() with CASE WHEN is old-fashioned PIVOT. You can use PIVOT-syntax as well, but this way is more flexible.
The magic happens in JSON_VALUE() where we can use the field's name in the json path.

Hint: You can use SELECT * FROM ... and take away the GROUP BY to look into the full result set.
If interested, you'd get the same with PIVOT.
SELECT p.*
FROM
(
    SELECT Cust.[name]
          ,Cust.[default]
          ,Cust.[description]
          ,JSON_VALUE(Env.customs, CONCAT('$.',Cust.[name])) AS ValueByFieldName
          ,Env.environment
    FROM OPENJSON(@json) WITH (environments NVARCHAR(MAX) AS JSON, customMetadata NVARCHAR(MAX) AS JSON) A

    CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(A.environments) 
    WITH (environment NVARCHAR(250)
         ,customs NVARCHAR(MAX) AS JSON) Env

    CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(A.customMetadata)
    WITH ([name] NVARCHAR(250)
         ,[default] NVARCHAR(250)
         ,[description] NVARCHAR(250)) Cust
) t
PIVOT
(
    MAX(ValueByFieldName) FOR environment IN(Development, Test, Production)
) p

